# Why Is Attribute Not Updating?

Tags: python, attributes

Why is the email attribute not updating but the first attribute,‘self.first’ is? I understand that the init method is only called when you create an object and it’s using the values passed into the object. However I updated the values in object and it updated the first attribute in the init method and the first attribute got printed correctly, why isn’t the 3rd attribute, ‘self.email’ which includes ‘self.first’?

I know you can create another method so the email gets printed correctly but I want to know why this specific method doesn’t work.

```
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@email.com'

    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)



emp_1 = Employee('John', 'Smith')

emp_1.first = 'Jim'

print(emp_1.first)
print(emp_1.email)
print(emp_1.fullname())
```

Comment: `self.email` is only set once in the constructor. If you want it to be dynamic, create a method for it.

Comment: In Python, you might also use a `property` for e-mail.

Comment: "why isn’t the 3rd attribute, ‘self.email’ which includes ‘self.first’?" **no that isn't how it works**. `self.email` does **not** "include" `self.first`. You set `self.email` to the *value of the expression `first + '.' + last + '@email.com'` inside your constructor. That experssion is only evaluated once. Consider, `x = 1; y = 2; z = x + y; x = 2; print(z)`... what do you expect that to print?

Comment: But ‘self.first’ gets reevaluated but ‘self.email’ doesn’t, this is the part I don’t get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the `email` value in the constructor, the expression `self.email = first + '.' + last + '@email.com'` is evaluated once and right away during the construction of a new object. That means Python builds a string from the values of the `first` and `last` parameters and saves that as a field in your Employee object. Since it is only constructed once, its value won't change even if you change the first or last name.

You seem to have expected that it would instead save the *logic* of how to construct an email string and re-evaluate that every time you want to access an employee's email address. You can do that yourself by adding a method or property which will be evaluated every time it is called:

```py
@property
def email(self):
    return f'{self.first}.{self.last}@email.com'
```

This way, the email address will reflect all updates to `first` and `last`. The first technique is called *eager evaluation* while the second approach is called *lazy evaluation*, if you want to read up more on the concepts behind this.

Answer (score 0):

The **init** method of a class is executed only once during instantiation of an instance of that class. If you are setting instance variables during **init** then they will not change unless explicitly modified.

Here is a more appropriate OO approach to this problem:-

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self._first = first
        self._last = last
    @property
    def email(self):
        return f'{self.first}.{self.last}@email.com'
    @property
    def first(self):
        return self._first
    @property
    def last(self):
        return self._last
    @first.setter
    def first(self, first):
        self._first = first
    @last.setter
    def last(self, last):
        self._last = last

E = Employee('John', 'Smith')
print(E.email)
E.first = 'Jim'
print(E.email)
E.last = 'Jones'
print(E.email)
```

Comment: The question is `why` not `how`.*

Comment: Why is answered in an earlier comment. This code is intended to show how it could be done. I will edit my answer to elaborate

Comment: In my example, I understand how constructors evaluated once, self.email evaluated once. What I don’t get is how is self.first reevaluated but self.email isn’t

Comment: It's because you explicitly modified 'first'. You did not modify 'email'

Comment: Then shouldn’t it modify all the attributes which include ‘first’?

Comment: No - because you haven't written any code to make it do that. You would have to reconstruct the email address outside of the class then set it explicitly